# tr command causes problems in cygwin bash.exe shell, but works in mintty.exe

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, sh, tr

I use Windows with cygwin. The following command should output the number of occurrences of '/' in the string "./bootstrp3.cab". It works when I use the mintty.exe shell and outputs "1":

```
echo ./bootstrp3.cab | tr -cd / | wc -c
```

Unfortunately it outputs the following message with the bash.exe shell

```
Usage:
tr [-cs] string1 string2
tr -s[-c] string1
tr -d[-c] string1
tr -ds[-c] string1 string2
```

It seems that the two shells behave differently, but they both seem to be the same kind of shell, because when I `echo $0`, bash.exe outputs `bash` and mintty.exe outputs `-bash`.

I also tried the command with the bourne shell (sh.exe), but it outputs the same message as with the bash.exe shell.

Does anyone know how I can get the command working with the sh.exe or bash.exe shell? And does someone know why the two bash shells behave differently?

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd say this isn't a bash issue, as `tr` is a standalone program. However, I don't know how the various Windows/cygwin shells are implemented; the various Unix utilities may be "built-in". One suggestion is to see if `tr -c -d` (specify each option separately) works in both.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work by separating the options. It outputs the same message. But thank you for trying to help. I could already work around the problem by using perreals suggestion.

Comment: MinTTY is a terminal, not a shell; you use a shell _in_ a terminal, and require both. How are you starting each one?

Comment: Also, what's the result of running `type tr` in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing using `sed` and `wc`:

```
echo -n ./bootstrp3.cab | sed 's![^/]!!g' | wc -c
```